# Word for a "blackened" and "abhorred" sky

Tags: single-word-requests

Salutations, I am looking for a single word that alludes to a sky that is very hated and repulsed due to its utter deathliness.

for example: "God's angels swarmed into the "nihility-like sky (THE REQUESTED WORD)" and painted it with a heavenly hue of red"

Now, it is most imperative for this word not to have any connotation with "incarnadine" and that "hell-firey" atmosphere which dystopian skies so often are presented with, but rather a sky abhorred for just how "dead" and "oblivion-like" it is--so I guess it would be a more by melancholy, maddening just because of how lifeless it is.

Thank you with perpetual heaven-lit skies.

Comment: Umm... *murky*?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul not distinctly what I am considering--rather a word which could replace "heavens" or "skies" or "globe" but not something that has the connotation of "hell" since that is sulfurous and fiery, but rather a sky of complete "nihility" P.S. I adore your username--HA!

Answer (score 1):

"Firmament" is a good one, and has a mythological feel which would appear to fit.

"Welkin" might also be a possibility, but it's more likely to be unfamiliar to the reader.

From "Dictionary.com" :

[Firmament](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/firmament?s=t) [ fur-muh-muh nt ]
noun.
the vault of heaven; sky.

[Welkin](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/welkin?s=t) [ wel-kin ]
noun Chiefly Literary.
the sky; the vault of heaven.

Comment: Could you say this, then: "We hollered at the clowder welkin, but it remained silent."?

Comment: @Conrado - I'd only do that if it was full of cats. If it was me, I'd have a besmirched firmament, but it's Vincent's call.

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere I have concluded to go with "crumbling-firmament" Thank you most colossally for the word, it complements the poem.

Comment: Please provide dictionary definitions and citations. Otherwise, the suggested words don't have any meaning within the context of the answer.

Comment: No; this does not even connote 'a sky _that is very hated and repulsed due to its utter deathliness_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I based the answer partly on Vincent's comment under the original question. Seemed to work for him (two comments above), though I - and I'm sure Vincent - are open to other suggestions.

Comment: If OP is happy with the answer 'firmament', the question becomes a duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Are you thinking of [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385597/what-do-you-call-the-night-sky/385600#385600)? I agree that it wasn't right in that context, but I think it works here. The Dickinson question approached it from the other angle - starting with the word. I'll happily respond to a vote to close as a duplicate, but I'd be happier upvoting a better answer. Any thoughts?

Comment: OP asks for a word for a “blackened” and “abhorred” sky. I'd say an answer with no reference to either of the “blackened” and “abhorred” aspects, essentially just a fancy, literary word for 'sky', isn't even ballpark. I'm not saying this doesn't fit with 'I need a word to use here', but it doesn't match the title question's request for _a word **for**_  'a “blackened” and “abhorred” sky'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - But it's a perfect fit for "Word for (a "blackened" and "abhorred") sky", and Vincent's comment under the question clarifies it's the sky that interests him. Grounds for an edit to the question, maybe, but again, he seemed to like one of the words I offered, so I can feel that SE has made the world a bit of a better place. I'm not sure what outcome you're hoping for, as deleting an answer that the questioner has found useful wouldn't seem to do anyone any good.